# Display form into the login page Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm very new in Drupal and I encounter a problem.

I want to add a login page. So I have the page http://localhost/mytheme/user/login

I don't know how to display the login form into that page ....

Thanks for your help !

Comment: localhost link is useless for us to help.

Comment: you have the login page at  http://localhost/mytheme/user

Answer (score 1):

First way. This is standard drupal's login form. You can use it on your custom pages
[user_login form](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_login/7)

Second way. [Rename Admin Paths](https://www.drupal.org/project/rename_admin_paths) module, which can rename you paths to standart user's operations. For example you have default `yousite.com/user/login` and you can set path to login as `yousite.com/mytheme/user/login` it's easy